# How do I tie a Prusik knot?

Tags: knots

Prusik knots are useful in emergency situations as they can be used for both climbing up a rope (out of a canyon) or down a rope (rappelling) without someone else providing a fireman's belay.

How would I go about properly tying a Prusik knot?

Comment: Similar knots are the [Autoblock aka French Prusik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoblock) and the [Klemheist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klemheist_knot) Inevitably there is some debate about their relative merits but both are defintely a bit easier to tie than the prusik. They are also a handy way of providing adjustable tension for a tarp ridge-line etc

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A Picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Illustration of a prussik knot]

Comment: I've used the first two steps a number of times. Is there much benefit to the additional loops?

Comment: Friction I could see, but the weight is still being put entirely on the two ends coming away from the knot. Thanks!

Comment: @TimothyStrimple More wraps = more friction.  You test it and see if it stops your descent with no hands.  If it slips, you add more wraps.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple in my experience, it depends on what kind of activity you are doing. If it is merely a safety measure for self-belay, one or two wraps should be sufficient because a fall would cinch the prusik very quickly. However, when I am using a pair of prusiks to ascend a rope, I usually want at least 3 wraps because I need the prusik to bite into the rope immediately so I don't lose any effort through sliding.

Comment: Rope thickness also matters. The bigger the difference between your ropes, the more likely you are to need a double or triple (the one in the picture) prusik knot.