# How to do a prussik with end of cordellete only?

Tags: knots, prusik

Doing a Prussik with a small cordellete that is tied together in a O is relatively easy. Now some maneuvers require to do a Prussik/blocking knot with only one side of a long cordelete... how do you do that?

Two situations where you may need the *end/middle of cordelette Prussik* (or any alternative knot with same feature) :

1. End of rope: crevasse rescue with double mariner/ Z drag (first pic)
2. Middle of rope: crevasse rescue with loop haul/one on one/austrian (second pic)

[image: double mariner/ Z drag]

[image]

Comment: or from a single strand? like so https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20271/how-to-tie-a-purcell-prusik-from-a-single-end-non-looped-rope

Comment: exactly! Not sure about being purcell or not (I fon't think the examples are), but the *from a single strand* is the correct answer, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tie a Purcell Prusik from a single end/ non looped rope?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20271/how-to-tie-a-purcell-prusik-from-a-single-end-non-looped-rope) Your welcome